# Diff command with file type exceptions

Tags: command-line, diff

While comparing 2 fairly big directories using `diff -rq ...` I want to exclude certain file types like `tar.gz` or `error_log`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU diff has options for doing this (see [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)):

```
   -x, --exclude=PAT
          exclude files that match PAT

   -X, --exclude-from=FILE
          exclude files that match any pattern in FILE
```

The pattern in each case is a glob (`*` for any number of characters):

```
diff -rq -x '*.tar.gz' -x '*error_log' foo bar
```

See for example:

- [How do you diff a directory for only files of a specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775377/how-do-you-diff-a-directory-for-only-files-of-a-specific-type)
- [How can I make 'diff -X' ignore specific paths and not file names?](https://superuser.com/questions/644680/how-can-i-make-diff-x-ignore-specific-paths-and-not-file-names)